# django model: get primary key of the model just created

Tags: python, django, django-models, primary-key

The Model is defined as below:

```
class UnitTab(models.Model):
    unit_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    create_time = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    update_time = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    read_db_connection = 'game_center_admin_db'
    write_db_connection = 'game_center_admin_db'

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'unit_tab'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        curr_time = int(time.time())
        if not self.create_time:
            self.create_time = curr_time
        self.update_time = curr_time
        super(UnitTab, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'unit_tab_%s' % (self.unit_id)
```

And I am just saving the a `UnitTab` with `UnitTab.objects.create()` to create a new object. The `unit_id` has `auto_increment`, so I did not have to set it.
But if I use `"u = UnitTab.objects.create()"`, the object `"u"` I get back is with `unit_id` as None — although the save is successful. So how can I can get the `primary key(unit_id)` of the `UnitTab` I just saved/created?

Edit: I am using Django 1.6.11 for my project

Edit: I logged those attributes and found that after `u.save()`, the `unit_id` is None. `create_time` is OK and the entity is saved successfully.

Edit: After changing from PositiveIntegerField to AutoField the `unit_id` field is auto assigned after save(). Just not sure why this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you don't want to use [`models.AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) instead?

```
unit_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: I just checked and using AutoField actually works. Just wonder why this happens

Comment: Er, because that's what AutoField does, and other fields don't.

Comment: But does "refresh" apply to all primary key fields? @Daniel

Answer (score 3):

After you create your new object:

`u = UnitTab.objects.create()`

follow it up by refreshing its value from the db using the `refresh_from_db()` method.

`u.refresh_from_db()`

You can find this info here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database

EDIT:

If you're on django 1.6, use the `save()` method and you should be able to access it like this:

```
>>> b2 = Blog(name='Cheddar Talk', tagline='Thoughts on cheese.')
>>> b2.id     # Returns None, because b doesn't have an ID yet.
>>> b2.save()
>>> b2.id     # Returns the ID of your new object.
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#auto-incrementing-primary-keys

Comment: Sadly I am using Django 1.6.11. Is there similar stuff in 1.6?

Comment: @JunchaoGu I updated my answer for you. Just use the `save()` method.

Comment: As the accepted answer suggested, using AutoField will just do the trick

Comment: @JunchaoGu AutoField just addressed the fact that your PK wasn't auto incrementing. Perhaps it was None type object to begin with, so by accessing it, you got None.

Comment: But supposedly--correct me if I am wrong, after calling save, `pk` should be filled with real value. when using PositiveIntegerField, after save the pk is still None. Using AutoField is fine

Comment: @JunchaoGu According to this, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#primary-key, Django should have managed that for you. Im not sure why it didn't :S